# Getting a new line on JLabel for variable string

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I have a 2d array with question content, which is loaded on a form on startup. I want to break the line after 25 characters, and add a new line after that, and set it as a `JLabel` text. "\n" doesn't work, so I tried html formatting, which only shows the first character of the text on the `JLabel`.

This is my current code:

```
        boolean alreadyset = false;

        if(questions[currentQuestion-1][1].length() > 25){
            char[] bytevalues = questions[currentQuestion-1][1].toCharArray();
            int counter = 0;
            String currentText;
            for(char x: bytevalues){
                if(counter==0)
                    jLabel5.setText(String.valueOf(x));
                else if(counter % 25 == 0){
                    currentText = jLabel5.getText();
                    jLabel5.setText("<html>"+ currentText + "<br>" + String.valueOf(x)+"</html>");
                }
                else if(counter!=0){
                    currentText = jLabel5.getText();
                    jLabel5.setText("<html>"+currentText + String.valueOf(x)+"</html>");
                }
                counter++;
            }
            alreadyset = true;
```

Thank you for your time in advance!

Comment: It would be helpful to show an example of "only shows the first character of the text on JLabel."

Comment: For better help, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We don't want to see your whole program, but rather you should condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles, has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem. You might very well solve the problem yourself by simply trying to isolate and expose the bug. Also, consider displaying the multi-lined text in a JTextArea and not a JLabel, one set to automatically wrap words.

Comment: It's not working because when counter%25==0 you set the value of the label after the <br> to valueOf(x), where x is a single character (you're looping on bytevalues).